# WP auto-login with query string key

Tags: wordpress, autologin

I'm trying to create the ability for subscribers to autologin with a unique key appended to the website URL. I used ACF to add the key text to the user detail page and the key is stored in the _usermeta table. I'm able to auto-login. However, when I go to pages beyond the landing page, the login appears to change to my login, based on echo of $current_user object.

For testing, I'm using a logged out Safari browser (which I never use). Using the URL with the special key in the query string logs in the user and displays the correct username and id when I echo those values.

The query string looks like:

http://website.com/?k=ABCD1234

Here's my code:

```html
function auto_login() {

 $user_key = $_GET['k'];

 global $wpdb;
 $user_id = $wpdb->get_var( " SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = '".$user_key."' ");

 wp_set_current_user($user_id);
 wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);

 global $current_user;
 $user = "";
 get_currentuserinfo();
 $user = $current_user->user_login;
 //echo $user;
}
add_action('init', 'auto_login');
```

It feels like the cookie is not being set (data/state is not maintained across pages). Any idea what is happening here? Thank you!

Comment: In looking at pluggable.php, it appears there might have been a conflict with $current_user as wp_set_current_user also uses it. However, when I remove the global $current_user line to //echo $user line, I still get the same behavior: I can echo the correct user id with the URL that includes the query string k= value but clicking to a second page switches to my login even though I'm not logged in and I've deleted all cookies related to this domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `plugins_loaded` action instead. The function `wp_set_current_user` will also fail if the user is already logged in so you should be checking that. Again with the validation, `$wpdb->get_var` could be returning `null` if nothing was found. For security, you should be escaping the SQL especially when dealing with logins and that statement could easily be manipulated.

```
function auto_login() {
    if (is_user_logged_in())
        return;

    $user_key = $_GET['k'];

    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = %s", $user_key));

    if (isset($user_id)) {
        wp_set_current_user($user_id);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);

        global $current_user;
        $user = "";
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user = $current_user->user_login;
        //echo $user;
    }
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'auto_login');
```

Comment: Yeah, I had not added anything like login checks until I got the code working. Are you positive $wpdb->prepare is needed for a select query? The documentation only shows update and insert.

Appreciate the plugins_loaded action idea. However, it doesn't echo values for testing. And it doesn't address the problem which is my login info is over-riding whatever is set with wp_set_current_user and wp_set_auth_cookie. Indeed, the cookie function doesn't appear to work. However, it's unclear if its because of WP or something in the Safari and Chrome browsers, even when I log out, quit the browser.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to find another machine and prove this is an issue on my computer with my web browsers. Appreciate the ideas for the plugins_loaded action and some of the wrapper code to optimize when the code is called.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here is the code I came up with that works. The only gotcha left is the cookie method appears to set a time limit of the browsing session, which is not an issue for me. I'll have to investigate how to extend the cookie time. Otherwise, perhaps this code is useful to someone else doing the same thing:

```html
function auto_login() {

 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  return;
 } else {

  if ( $_GET['k'] ) {

   $user_key = $_GET['k'];

   global $wpdb;
   $sql = $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = %s ", $_GET['k'] );
   $user_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

   if ( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
   } else {
    //alert stripe div with message/email link
   }

   //only used for testing code above
   if ($_GET['k']) {
    echo $user_id;
    echo $sql;
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
     echo $user->get_error_message();
   }
  }

 }
}
add_action('init', 'auto_login');
```

Also note, per ub3rst4r above, you can use the plugins_loaded action which precedes the init action. And last, I used the ACF plugin to create a text field for Users to store the unique user key value stored in the _usermeta table.